# How to get the first letter of each word in a string of dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column of first and last names. I want to extract the initials from the names as another column in my dataframe. For the following dataframe:

```
   Name
0 'Brad Pitt'
1 'Bill Gates'
2 'Elon Musk'
```

I have came up with a solution:

```
df['initials'] = [df['Name'][i].split()[0][0] + df['Name'][i].split()[1][0] for i in range(len(df))]
```

However, for a name such as 'John David Smith', this does not work, as I want to have the first letter of each word in a name. Moreover, since my dataframe is quite large, I would like to know if there is a 'vectorized' solution (without `for` loops).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension if performance is important with `split` and join:

```
df['initials'] = [' '.join(y[0] for y in x.split()) for x in df['Name']]
print (df)
         Name initials
0   Brad Pitt      B P
1  Bill Gates      B G
2   Elon Musk      E M
```

Or:

```
df['initials'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(y[0] for y in x.split()))
```

Solution with no `for`, but is is really slow:

```
df['initials'] = df['Name'].str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str[0]).fillna('').agg(' '.join, axis=1).str.rstrip()
```

Performmance for **400k** rows:

```
print (df)
               Name
0         Brad Pitt
1        Bill Gates
2         Elon Musk
3  John David Smith

df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
```

Fastest is second and first solution, then first @mozway answer, slowiest is second @mozway solution:

```
In [178]: %%timeit
     ...: df['initials2'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(y[0] for y in x.split()))
     ...: 
442 ms ± 3.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [177]: %%timeit
     ...: df['initials1'] = [' '.join(y[0] for y in x.split()) for x in df['Name']]
     ...: 
     ...: 
485 ms ± 7.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [180]: %%timeit
     ...: df['initials'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'(?<=\w)\w', '', regex=True)
     ...: 
830 ms ± 8.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [179]: %%timeit 
     ...: df['initials3'] = df['Name'].str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str[0]).fillna('').agg(' '.join, axis=1).str.rstrip()
     ...: 
18.8 s ± 772 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [181]: %%timeit
     ...: df['initials'] = (df['Name'].str.extractall(r'(?<!\w)(\w)').groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join))                 
     ...: 
     ...: 
25.3 s ± 692 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: the size of my dataframe can be around 12-18 millions rows of data. @jezrael

Comment: @MatasM - thank you, added performance comparison - my solutions and mozway solutions

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy using a short regex:

```
df['initials'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'(?<=\w)\w+', '', regex=True)
```

Alternative:

```
df['initials'] = (df['Name'].str.extractall(r'(?<!\w)(\w)')
                  .groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
                 )
```

output:

```
               Name initials
0         Brad Pitt      B P
1        Bill Gates      B G
2         Elon Musk      E M
3  John David Smith    J D S
```

#### how is works

##### solution 1:

- find each set of letter(s) that is not the first of a word
- delete it

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ELb4bk/1)

##### solution 2:

- find all first letters
- join them with a space

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XHcDDl/1)